# Invalid value io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.MockSchemaRegistryClient@4788c0a1 for configuration schema.registry.url

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am writing Integration test for Kafka avro Consumer with Schema registry but facing below error:

> Caused by: io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.MockSchemaRegistryClient@4788c0a1 for configuration schema.registry.url: Expected a comma separated list.

Below is my code:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, topics = { "abc.v1" })
@DirtiesContext
public class KafkaConfigAbstractTest {

    private static final String TEST_TOPIC = "abc.v1";

    @Autowired(required=true)
    EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;
    private Schema schema;
    private MockSchemaRegistryClient mockSchemaRegistryClient = new MockSchemaRegistryClient();

    private String avroSchema = MyClass.SCHEMA$.toString();

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
        schema = parser.parse(avroSchema);

        mockSchemaRegistryClient.register("Test-value", schema);
    }

    @Test
    public void consumeKafkaMessage_receive_sucess() {

        Consumer<String, MyClass> consumer = configureConsumer();
        Producer<String, MyClass> producer = configureProducer();
        MyClass object = MyClass.newBuilder()
                .setId("1")
                .setName("test")
                .build();

        ProducerRecord<String, MyClass> prodRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, MyClass>(TEST_TOPIC, object);

        producer.send(prodRecord);

        ConsumerRecord<String, MyClass> singleRecord = KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumer, TEST_TOPIC);
        assertNotNull(singleRecord.value());

        consumer.close();
        producer.close();

    }

    private Consumer<String, MyClass> configureConsumer() {
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("abc", "true", embeddedKafkaBroker);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        Consumer<String, MyClass> consumer = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, MyClass>(consumerProps).createConsumer();
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(TEST_TOPIC));
        return consumer;
    }

    private Producer<String, MyClass> configureProducer() {
        Map<String, Object> producerProps = new HashMap<>(KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafkaBroker));
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomKafkaAvroSerializer.class);
        producerProps.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, mockSchemaRegistryClient);
        producerProps.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, "false");
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, MyClass>(producerProps).createProducer();
    }

}
```

And if I change the schema registry url in producer properties like below

```
   producerProps.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://mock:8081");
```

I get below error :

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema: {"type":"record","name":"MyClass","namespace":"com.kafka.test","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"int"},{"name":"name","type":"String"}]}
>
> Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema Not Found; error code: 404001

Note: I have already created custom Avro serializer and deserializer and given the urls in my application.properties

application.properties looks like:

```
server.port = 8081
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding = true

spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers = ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
kafka.bootstrap-servers = ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}

spring.kafka.producer.properties.schema.registry.url= http://mock:8081
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer = com.kafka.user.mock.CustomKafkaAvroSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.group-id = abc

spring.kafka.consumer.properties.schema.registry.url= http://mock:8081
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer = com.kafka.user.mock.CustomKafkaAvroDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id = abc
spring.kafka.auto.offset.reset = earliest

spring.kafka.producer.auto.register.schemas= true
spring.kafka.properties.specific.avro.reader= true
```

Comment: Do you need to use Spring? Have you looked how Confluent themselves writes unit tests with the Mock registry?

Comment: Will check on it. Thanks for suggesting !